# How to show a popup on datagrid button click in wpf c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, popup

I have a common popup in my wpf window and I have a button in the datagrid as well. What I want is to open the popup when the button is clicked. The popup should be independent to each button click. For example, let's say that I have two rows in the datagrid. When I click on the first button popup should appear,then I do some changes to that popup and close it. Now I click the second button it should open a new popup instead of the changes I made before. I'm using a common popup for this. Please anyone tell me is it possible to handle my requirement with common popup window?

**XAML**

```
<Popup x:Name="popUpServer" IsOpen="False" Placement="MousePoint" >
                        <Border Background="#FFEFF2F3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="229" Height="145">
                            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,-17">
                                <Grid Width="227" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                                    <GroupBox Header="Configuration" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,6,-9,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="125" Width="211">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Label Content="Auto Restart" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,6,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                            <ToggleSwitch:HorizontalToggleSwitch  x:Name="tsAutoRestart" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="97,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="46" ThumbSize="22" Height="21" RenderTransformOrigin="3.522,1.048">
                                                <ToggleSwitch:HorizontalToggleSwitch.UncheckedBackground>
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFC80000" Offset="1"/>
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF0A0A0A" Offset="0.853"/>
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                </ToggleSwitch:HorizontalToggleSwitch.UncheckedBackground>
                                                <ToggleSwitch:HorizontalToggleSwitch.CheckedBackground>
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#000000" />
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#000000" Offset="1" />
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                </ToggleSwitch:HorizontalToggleSwitch.CheckedBackground>
                                                <ToggleSwitch:HorizontalToggleSwitch.ThumbBrush>
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFD6D4D4" />
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFD6D4D4" Offset="1" />
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFD6D4D4" Offset="0.02" />
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                </ToggleSwitch:HorizontalToggleSwitch.ThumbBrush>
                                            </ToggleSwitch:HorizontalToggleSwitch>
                                            <ComboBox x:Name="cbDuration" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" Margin="97,40,0,0">
                                                <ComboBoxItem Content="30 Minutes"/>
                                                <ComboBoxItem Content="1 Hours"/>
                                                <ComboBoxItem Content="2 Hours"/>
                                            </ComboBox>
                                            <Label Content="After" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="83" Margin="9,36,0,0"/>
                                            <Button x:Name="btnApply" Content="Apply" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="125,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64" Click="BtnApply_Click"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </GroupBox>

                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
```

**Datagrid**

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel>
                                                <Button x:Name="txtServerInfo" Click="TxtServerInfo_Click" Height="23" Width="28">
                                                    <Button.Background>
                                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="img.png"/>
                                                    </Button.Background>
                                                </Button>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**Code behind file**

```
 private void TxtServerInfo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            popUpServer.IsOpen = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a common popup means better create a popup in a separate user control.then for a button click you can create a new object for the user control and then open the popup by using the user controls object.then the values inside the popup will be independent of the previous button click.

Answer (score 0):

please try the next solution; combine your popup with the button into a separate user control, in that way you can trigger the popup opening based on the button click, and for each button click there will be it's(button) own popup opened there. When you combine the popup and the button together they will have the same data context, thus you will have no problem to make a binding, from the other hand if you want a different data contexts for these controls you can support the user with two dependency properties form that a combined user control.

I'll glad to help if you will have problems with the code, let me know about that.
Regards.